# slicing all the columns of a dataframe simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-processing

I have a data frame of an ECG. The data frame consists of 12 columns (lead in ECG vocabulary). I want to cut some slices of all columns like the image below.
I find the peak of the first column and define the length of the cut and slice all the columns simultaneously.
**Edit:** In fact, I choose the highest peaks of the first column (lead) and stack them in a list named pos. Then, I use these peaks as my reference line and cut for ex 500 data points before and 500 data points after the reference line and stack them in the list named cut.
This is my code but I get the error "list assignment index out of range"

```
def slicing (patient, pos, len):
   
   cut = []
   for lead in patient:
     for position in pos: 
        cut[position] = patient.loc[:, str(lead)][(position - len) : (position + len)]
        print (cut)
```

Could you please tell me how can I fix the error and how can I have my slices be named like
cut[1] = [...]
cut[2] = [...]

Comment: what is in `pos`? please provide a fully reproducible example

Comment: Hello dear, may you add more context to your code? add comments to describe what you are trying to do and you can share some of the data as a link to google drive file in order to be able to work through the task you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Of course, I add more details in edit part. Hope this is more clear now @mozway

Comment: @Totoro yes be we need a reproducible input (not an image, no `...`), and the matching expected output. Make a small example, no need for a full dataset!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"list assignment index out of range"` - this is because you are trying to assign a value to an index which is not present in the list. try `append()`

Instead of just using for loop try `enumerate()` and `rename()` function for each slice

Example:

```
for i, lead in enumerate(patient.columns):
        for j, position in enumerate(pos):

            slice_name = f"cut{i+1}_{j+1}"

            cut.append(patient.loc[:, lead][(position - length) : (position + length)].rename(slice_name))
return cut
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works exactly as I wanted. enumerate is a great suggestion. Thanks again!

Comment: @Totoro but you could likely achieve your goal without a loop using vectorial code… anyway if you're happy with a loop

Comment: I'm always interested in optimizing the codes. Could you please tell me a bit about vectorial code in my example please?